# Convergence of Integrals - A Problem

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, integral-inequality

> Suppose $f$ is positive and increasing on $[0, +\infty)$. Suppose that $F(x)=$$\int_0^x f(t)dt$. Prove that $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {1}{f(x)} dx$$ converges if and only if $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac {x}{F(x)} dx$$ converges.

*My thoughts, and attempt at solution* -

Since $f$ is increasing, $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\le\int_0^xf(x)\,dt=xf(x).$ We can rearrange that to $\frac1{f(x)}\le\frac{x}{F(x)}.$ Hence if the integral of $\frac{x}{F(x)}$ converges, then so does the integral of $\frac1{f(x)}.$

However, the above working seems incomplete as it bounds the integral from the upper side only. In fact, it shows that if the second integral converges, then the first one *may* converge, but not vice versa. How do I place a lower bound on the integral, and go about the rest of the solution?

Haven't been able to proceed from here, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the lower bound, for $x>0$, we have that $f(x)>0$, $F(x)>0$ and, since $f$ is increasing, it follows that
$$xf(x)=(2x-x)f(x)\leq \int_x^{2x}f(t)dt=F(2x)-F(x)\leq F(2x)\implies \frac{x}{F(2x)}\leq \frac{1}{f(x)}.$$
Hence
$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{F(t)}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{F(2x)}dx\leq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}dx.$$

P.S. Note that $F(0)=0$ and by L'Hopital
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x}{F(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{f(0)}$$
which implies that $x/F(x)$ is integrable in a right neighbourhood of $0$.