# $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ converges if and only if $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{F(x)}dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Suppose $f$ is positive and increasing on $[0, +\infty)$. Let $F(x) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$.

How do we show that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{f(x)}$ converges if and only if $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{F(x)}dx$ converges?

I was thinking of using the comparison test, but I can't really find a way to connect the two integrals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked yesterday, but I could not find the related post.

We see that $xf(x)\leq\displaystyle\int_{x}^{2x}f(t)dt\leq F(2x)$, so $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2x}{F(2x)}dx=\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{F(x)}dx$.

On the other hand, $F(x)\leq xf(x)$, so $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{F(x)}dx\geq\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx$.

Comment: It has been asked 3 days ago. See my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748249/convergence-of-integrals-a-problem/2748259#2748259

Comment: BTW $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2x}{F(2x)}dx$ is NOT equal to $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x}{F(x)}dx$

Comment: There is another factor $1/2$, thanks for reminding.